# When to use aspnet_regiis.exe to encrypt configs?

Tags: asp.net, aspnet-regiis.exe

I understand how you can use the following to encrypt and decrypt elements of configuration, such as connection strings:

**Encrypt**:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "connectionStrings" C:\path\to\application
```

**Decrypt**:

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf "connectionStrings" C:\path\to\application
```

My question is very simple, but what is the use case for this?

For example, if you have the following timeline of activities:

1. Encrypt web.config
2. Time when configuration is liable to be visible by a 3rd party
3. Decrypt web.config

What is the situation under which #2 is thought possible/likely to arise? Is it during deployment time?

(I initially assumed the data would stay encrypted, and the application would read that encrypted data, decrypt it, then use it but I can see this is not the case).

Comment: There are many scenarios, Basically you don't want that someone with access to the File System to know your connection string data, e.g., The app developer doesn't and shouldn't know Connection Strings in production, but he needs to get into the server to update the app.

Comment: The web.config remains encrypted even while the aplication is running? That's what I initially assumed but articles and other questions I read made it sound like that wasn't the case. So how do you read an encrypted connection string in order for the application to still work or does it work same as normal i.e. using ConfigurationManager?

Comment: Yes, the configuration remains encrypted and it's transparent for the app, share the articles where they say it's not like that.